# Origin of the term "derived subgroup"

Tags: group-theory

The commutator subgroup *G'*, generated by all commutators of a group *G*, is also called the *derived subgroup*. Why is this; are there any concrete analogies with analytical derivatives (apart from the notation) which justify this name, or is this merely an established expression?

Comment: It doesn't even satisfy a nice Leibniz rule, since $(A\times B)'=A'\times B'$...

Comment: Don't let the apostrophe mislead you. The meaning is simply [closer to non-mathematical English](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/derive) than you may think. If you ever dig deeper into homological algebra you will encounter derived functors, derived categories,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [groupprops](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Derived_subgroup) one can find the following historical remark: 
*The notion of derived subgroup or commutator subgroup naturally arose in the context of finding a natural choice for a good composition series for a solvable group.*

The result is the *derived series*, with $G$, $[G,G]$, $[[G,G],[G,G]]$ etc.

Comment: That explains why commutator subgroups are important enough to merit a special name, but why *that* particular name?

Comment: The group $[G,G]$ is "derived" from $G$, i.e., arises naturally from $G$ in the context of composition series. So the name is not special, but just very ordinary, in the sense of "arises" from $G$.

Comment: To put it another way, not everything that is derivative is a derivative.

Comment: Rather disappointing :) I was hoping for some connection with Lie groups for instance (which I am not really acquainted with, but do have derivatives involved).

Comment: yes, I agree, but I also see no other connections. As Jyrki says, there are a lot of derived functors, derived categories etc.

Comment: There is also a connection to Lie algebra's and brackets.

Comment: In C. Jordan's 1870 "*traité des substitutions*" (which is a cornerpoint in the development of group theory), "*derived group [groupe dérivé]*" (p.22) is used in the modern sense of "subgroup generated".

Comment: In the Séguier 1904 memoir, he again uses "derived" in this "generated by" sense, but then called "*derivé de $G$" the [sub]group  "derived by commutators", that is, the subgroup generated by commutators. So this is the modern sense, and derived means derived from commutators. It should be checked whether this meaning is already existing in previous literature, notably Burnside/Frobenius/Dyck (or even Cayley, Sylow?).