# What is the relation between "derivations" and the "derived subalgebra" of a Lie algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

As I understand the term "derivation" in the context of Lie Algebra $L$ is a $\delta\in End(L)$ such that $\delta$ satisfies "Leibniz's rule" or what is often called product rule for differentiation.

The derivations form a Lie-subalgebra of $End(L)$ under the Lie-bracket.

There is also the derived subalgebra which is the Lie-subalgebra generated by $\{ [x,y]:x,y\in L\}$. It is somewhat analogous to the derived subgroup.

My question which I think is quite natural is what is the exact relationship between a derivation and derived subalgebra. Or to put it more clearly, since these names are very similar there must be some kind of relationship. (I thought that the set of derivations $Der(L)\subset End(L)$ is a derived subalgebra of $End(L)$. i.e. $Der(L)=[End(L),End(L)]$. But I am pretty sure, this is not quite true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $Der(L)$ need not be $[End(L),End(L)]$. For an abelian Lie algebra $L$ of dimension $n$ over $K$ we have $Der(L)=End(L)$, but
$[End(L),End(L)]=[M_n(K),M_n(K)]$, which is the vector space of traceless matrices of size $n$.

The derived ideal $[L,L]$ equals $ad(L)(L)$, where $ad(L)$ is the space of inner derivations.

Comment: Thank you. Then, is there no explicit relationship between the two similarly coined terms

Comment: Apparently not; the name "derived", see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331357/origin-of-the-term-derived-subgroup) might not come from "derivation", but of course the derivative is essential for the correspondence between Lie groups and Lie algebras.